# Code that corrects a length $s$ burst error

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Show that exists an $(n,k)=(155,135)$ binary code that corrects burst errors of length $6$.

P.S. A  Code with length $n$  fixes burst error (pattern) of length $s$ if the error set of this code consists of sets of length $n$ whose non-zero components are located in $s$  consecutive bits, that is, in each such set, the locations of the first and last non-zero components differ by no more than $s - 1$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by (or perhaps add a link that explains) $(n,k) = (155,135)$? $n$ is apparently the "length of the code", but what is $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you want to correct a burst of length $s,$ your code must have the property that no two codewords differ by the sum of two (non overlapping) bursts of length $s.$

This leads to the Rieger bound, that $n-k\geq 2s$. So your parameters satisfy this. However, you probably need to look up Fire codes which would actually achieve a so called *burst error correction efficiency ratio* given by
$$
\frac{2s}{n-k} \geq 2/3.
$$
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The field of 32 elements, $GF(32)$ or $\Bbb{F}_{32}$, whichever name you prefer, has $31$ non-zero elements. Each element can be represented by a block of five bits in several ways. As $155=5\cdot31$, this is just what the doctor ordered.

A burst of length $6$ cannot disturb more than two (consecutive) $5$-bit symbols. Therefore a code correcting two symbol errors can handle bursts like this.

The Reed-Solomon codes are MDS, so a $32$-ary RS code with $(n,k)=(31,27)$ has minimum distance $d=n-k+1=5$. Therefore it can correct any two symbol errors, and the problem is solved as $135=5\cdot27$.

---

That RS-code does not care whether the two errorneous symbols are consecutive or not. Making this a bit of a cheat solution. But, hey, it works :-)

Comment: Actually we can make RS-codes of length  $32$ with this alphabet field. The engineers often prefer to use the cyclic variant (when we have the mechanism of generator polynomials available). It fits the numerology of the quesion perfectly, so...